# Error expression of non-boolean from stored procedure when exec

Tags: sql-server

I have a sample of stored procedure, and when I am running this stored procedure, I get following error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected,near 'aa'.

This is my query, please help me to fix this errors.

Thanks.

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE STP_SummaryOutstandingPO  
     @kodeProject varchar(20),  
     @TanggalPaymentAwal datetime,
     @TanggalPaymentAkhir datetime 
 AS  
 BEGIN  
      DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
      DECLARE @Conditions1 as varchar(max);
      DECLARE @Conditions2 as varchar(max);
      DECLARE @Conditions3 as varchar(max); 

      IF (@TanggalPaymentAwal IS NOT NULL) OR (LEN(@TanggalPaymentAwal) > 0)
          SET @Conditions1 = ' and b.TanggalCP between '+convert(nvarchar(25), @TanggalPaymentAwal, 121)+ ' and '+convert(nvarchar(25), @TanggalPaymentAkhir, 121)+'';       
      ELSE
          SET @Conditions1 = ' ';

      IF ((@kodeProject IS NOT NULL) OR (LEN(@kodeProject) > 0) AND (@TanggalPaymentAwal IS NOT NULL) OR (LEN(@TanggalPaymentAwal) > 0))    
          SET @Conditions2 = ' a.KodeProject='+@kodeProject+' and cc.TanggalCP between '+convert(nvarchar(25), @TanggalPaymentAwal, 121)+' and '+convert(nvarchar(25), @TanggalPaymentAkhir, 121)+'';
      ELSE IF ((@kodeProject IS NOT NULL) OR (LEN(@kodeProject) > 0) AND (@TanggalPaymentAwal IS NULL) OR (LEN(@TanggalPaymentAwal) = 0))   
          SET @Conditions2 = ' a.KodeProject='+@kodeProject+'';
      ELSE IF ((@kodeProject IS NULL) OR (LEN(@kodeProject) = 0) AND (@TanggalPaymentAwal IS NOT NULL) OR (LEN(@TanggalPaymentAwal) > 0))   
          SET @Conditions2 = ' cc.TanggalCP between '+convert(nvarchar(25), @TanggalPaymentAwal, 121)+' and '+convert(nvarchar(25), @TanggalPaymentAkhir, 121)+'';  

      SET @SQLString = ''
      SET @SQLString += ' select a.KodeProject, a.KodePO, a.TanggalPO, a.JobNumber, a.Keterangan, b.NamaSupplier, a.NamaProject, DPP=a.TotalNetto, a.PPN, a.Total as PO_Amount,'  
      SET @SQLString += ' total_pembayaran=ISNULL((select SUM(aa.AmountOriginalD) from TCashVoucherDetail as aa (NOLOCK) left join TCashVoucherHeader as b on aa.KodeCP=b.KodeCP'
      SET @SQLString += ' where NoPO=a.KodePO),0),'
      SET @SQLString += ' tanggal_payment=('
      SET @SQLString += ' Select '' # ''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),aa.TanggalCP,106)  AS [text()] '
      SET @SQLString += ' From TCashVoucherHeader as aa (NOLOCK)'
      SET @SQLString += ' inner join TCashVoucherDetail as bb (NOLOCK) on aa.KodeCP=bb.KodeCP'
      SET @SQLString += ' Where bb.NoPO=a.KodePO'
      SET @SQLString += ' group by aa.TanggalCP'
      SET @SQLString += ' order by aa.TanggalCP'
      SET @SQLString += ' For XML PATH ('')'
      SET @SQLString += ' )'  
      SET @SQLString += ' from TPOHeader as a (NOLOCK)'  
      SET @SQLString += ' left join'
      SET @SQLString += ' ('
      SET @SQLString += ' select aa.TanggalCP, bb.NoPO'
      SET @SQLString += ' from TCashVoucherHeader as aa (NOLOCK)'
      SET @SQLString += ' inner join TCashVoucherDetail as bb (NOLOCK) on aa.KodeCP=bb.KodeCP' 
      SET @SQLString += ' group by aa.TanggalCP, bb.NoPO'
      SET @SQLString += ' )as cc on a.KodePO=cc.NoPO'
      SET @SQLString += ' left join TSupplier as b (NOLOCK) on a.KodeSupplier=b.KodeSupplier'
      SET @SQLString += ' where a.KodeProject='+@kodeProject+''
      SET @SQLString += ' group by' 
      SET @SQLString += ' a.KodeProject, a.KodePO, a.TanggalPO, a.JobNumber, a.Keterangan, b.NamaSupplier, a.NamaProject,'
      SET @SQLString += ' a.TotalNetto, a.PPN, a.Total'
      SET @SQLString += ' order by a.KodePO';

      EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString;    
END
```

Answer (score 2):

The length of @SQLString should be increased , The end of 500 chars is as following

```
SET @SQLString += ' inner join TCashVoucherDetail as bb (NOLOCK) on aa
```

that is the reason of:

```
 "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected,near 'aa'.".
```

Solution:

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(4000); -- instead of 500
```

Comment: not work, and i get a new error : "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ') ) from TPOHeader as a (NOLOCK) left join ( select..."

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the `PRINT @SQLString` with the `EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString;` to see the query that is being executed(your query will not be executed).

It seems that the length of the @SQLString is not large enough to store the query, so your string is being truncated. to solve this, simply define @SQLString as NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: not work, and i get a new error : "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ') ) from TPOHeader as a (NOLOCK) left join ( select..."